# Rails - how to instantiate a model with a secondary association? Is there an alternative to the << operator for instantiated records?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, parent-child

**Context:**

With Rails & ActiveRecord, my understanding is that if you want an instantiated, not yet saved, child & its attributes to be accessed via a parent, you need to instantiate the child record through the parent. For example:

```
# when instantiated through parent
order = ParentA.last.orders.new(notes:"asdf")
order.notes
> "asdf"
order.parent_a.present?
> true
order.parent_a.orders.map(&:notes)
> ["asdf"]

# when NOT instantiated through parent
order = Order.new(parent_a_id:ParentA.last.id, notes: "asdf")
order.notes
> "asdf"
order.parent_a.present?
> true
order.parent_a.orders.map(&:notes)
> []
```

In the above example, I want the first scenario to occur, but where I have to instantiate `order` across 2 parents, `ParentA` and `ParentB`. I.e., something like...

```
order = ParentA.last.orders.new(notes:"asdf")
ParentB.last.orders << order 

order.parent_a.orders.map(&:notes)
> ["asdf"]
order.parent_b.orders.map(&:notes)
> ["asdf"]
```

Now actually the above code DOES work IF order is valid, since to use the `<<` operator, `order` basically has to be a fully valid child object.

However, in my case, I want to do instantiation now and order later. In other words, I'm almost wondering if there's an alternative to `<<` that can associate an instantiated child on a parent?

Also note the `<<` operator will also save an additional record if the instantiated `order` object is valid, so depending on circumstance, that may be bad

Answer (score 0):

The point of the shovel operator is really just to implicitly associate two items. You can always assign the assocation or foreign key values directly:

```
order = ParentA.last.orders.new(notes:"asdf", parent_b: ParentB.last)
order.save 
ParentB.last.orders.last == order # should be true
```

Comment: So unfortunately this way of instantiating does not allow `order` attributes to be accessible via parent before save, which is what I'm looking for. I.e., right after `order` is defined in your code, I would like to be able to run: `order.parent_b.orders.map(&:notes) == ["asdf"]`